# All Third party sip library sample project contains lot of error .How to proceed

Tags: android, sip, sipdroid, mjsip, csip-simple

At first I wanted to use native sip apis to implement sip calling in android app and it is working fine but in some devices like CANVAS 3, Samsung S2,s3 it was not working .After debugging I found this line of code was returning NULL

**manager = SipManager.newInstance(ctx);**

That measns that device does not support Sip Apis.But on the same device other application for sipcalling like SipDroid etc are working properly.How it is possible ?Are they do not use native sip Apis??

So started looking for third party support but all the library has only one open source project and I get lot of errors on importing these project.

[sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout) using [mjsip](http://mjsip.org/mjua.html) lib

[csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/checkout) using [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org)

[imsdroid](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/source/checkout) using [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org)

I have tried many times to build it and start it on the android emulator without any success. The source code does not build and generates about 1500 errors. In the meantime, when I downloaded the apk file for the app, it runs on the emulator without any problems.

I have searched the internet and did not find any specific issue in public about  causes of that problem.

I am wondering if the source code on the official web site has some bug(s) that the actual app does not have, and you did not have a chance yet to add the corrections to the public source code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [project](https://github.com/fingi/csipsimple) based on CSipSimple working perfectly i have used this once and it compiles without any error. It might be helpful to you.

Comment: something is missing bcoz while importing eclipse says  `No projects are found to import`

Comment: then create one project and copy all the files in that project

Comment: now also it is having bugs ..Is pjsip is paid library

Comment: i have used this project once it was working fine may be they have changed something.

Comment: Thanks man for giving ur valuable time.I'll go through linphone ..If u have any working project sample of sip plz share with me at ayazshakeeb@gmail.com

Comment: actually i don't have any project i have used the same which i have shared with you